# I did not set a breakpoint but entered a breakpoint. I used vscode to debug the program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, malloc, breakpoints, free

I did not set breakpoints. My main program controls the acquisition of input and then performs verification. The first input is OK, but after one input content verification, the second verification will enter breakpoint mode. The program breaks in the sentence shown in the picture. Then I need to click Continue two or three times to continue the normal execution of the program. I want to ask why this happens?

[No breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GQqp.jpg)

Code of calling function with breakpoint in main program:

```
  /* Verify whether the entered value is each value between 1 and max_value */
  while(checkForDuplicationForNums(key, key_length_m)  /* Check whether the entered value is repeated */
    || checkElemExceedsMax(key, key_length_m) 
    || checkNumWithinMaxNotAppear(key, key_length_m)) {
        illegalInputPrompt();
        getInputNumArrayByGetchHaveSpaces(key_string, key);
  }
```

Code snippet for breakpoint occurrence:

```
int checkForDuplicationForNums(int nums[], int max_value){
  int* within_max_value = (int *)calloc(max_value, sizeof(int)); 
  for(int i=0; i<max_value; i++) {
    /* nums : 0~m-1 */
    within_max_value[nums[i]]++;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<max_value; i++) {
    if(within_max_value[i] > 1) {
      return 1; 
    }
  }
  free(within_max_value);
  return 0;
}
```

The location of the strange breakpoint:
`free(within_max_value);`

[Program execution effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjtOq.jpg)

The max_value is always 11 during the program running.

The first input makes the nums:

`int nums[11] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`

The second input makes the nums:

`int nums[11] = {0, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};`

Then the program breaking. nums[1] exceeds the value range of my expected input value: 1~11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second loop iteration of the second function call, the line

```
within_max_value[nums[i]]++;
```

is writing to the array `within_max_value` out of bounds.

According to the information provided in your question, in the second function call, `num[1]` will have the value `11`. This means that the line

```
within_max_value[nums[i]]++;
```

is equivalent to

```
within_max_value[11]++;
```

in the second loop iteration of the second function call.

That expression is accessing the array `within_max_value` out of bounds, because valid indexes are `0` up to and including `10`. The index `11` is out of bounds.

By writing to the array out of bounds, you are probably corrupting heap memory, which causes the next call to `free` to generate an exception, which causes the debugger to stop at that line.

Comment: I'm sorry that the nums array I provided is incorrect. Getting the input nums value from cmd is exactly as described in the problem description, but before the nums array is passed into the function, its value has been operated with -1, which means that nums is `int nums[11] = {0, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};`



But your answer is correct. I checked and found that the value 11 of nums [1] is out of the range, `within_max_value[11]++;` causing the exception you described. Thank you very much! Thank you for your patience, which makes me feel warm.

Comment: @goon: I am pleased that I was able to help. I have now adapted my answer to your updated question.

Comment: I've seen it~Thanks again :) @Andreas Wenzel